# trying to merge data from a broken up report back into a master (index utilized)

Tags: excel, vba

Frequent listener but 1st time caller so please go easy. Self taught VBA through a lot of research here, YouTube, Google, etc and trial and error.

Wrote a script to break up a large report into individual smaller reports for each person with no other data in the report other than their own rows for privacy reasons (ex. their rows could be in rows 5, 27, 88, 257 and another file be 7, 558, 620, but all of the other rows are blank). Their reports are saved filtered though so their rows display consecutively. Now that each of them has completed it and sent it back to me, I saved all of these reports in a specific directory ("blah") and wrote another script trying to merge it back into 1 master file.

It seems to work great when I give it only a few files to run through but upon going through, say, 100, it starts pulling data from some other files in other directories and meshing them into the set destinations cells (Q,R,S,T,V). Ran many times with the destination (Master) file open, and even closed all other workbooks just to be sure. This macro is under my personal.xlsb where I have a few other macros saved, but I'm running just this one.

I know my `I=2 to 1000` isn't the most efficient way to run though it but it seems fast enough for the at most a few hundred reports I'll need to use it to combine at any given time.

```
Sub MergeBackReport()
Dim wbkS As Workbook 'used ___S as "S"ource
Dim wbkD As Workbook 'and ___D as "D"estination to make it easier for me to follow
Dim wshD As Worksheet
Dim strFile As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim i, c As Long
c = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wshD = ActiveSheet 'my current open Master report that I'm meshing the data back into just for the select cells below
Path = "\\blah\" 'where I'm reading the received worksheets from
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Filename <> "" 'runs while there's files in the blah directory to run through
        'MsgBox (Filename) 'just a check to see which file it opened, seems fine
        Set wbkS = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wshS = wbkS.Worksheets(1)
        For i = 2 To 1000
            If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i).Value) Then 'looking for the 1st non empty row with data, the 1st column being the index of where I need it to paste.
                'MsgBox (i) "just checking the above, seems fine
                wshD.Range("Q" & i).Value = wshS.Range("Q" & i).Value '1st cell I need to populate
                wshD.Range("R" & i).Value = wshS.Range("R" & i).Value '2nd cell I need to populate
                wshD.Range("S" & i).Value = wshS.Range("S" & i).Value '3rd cell I need to populate
                wshD.Range("T" & i).Value = wshS.Range("T" & i).Value '4th cell I need to populate
                wshD.Range("V" & i).Value = wshS.Range("V" & i).Value '5th cell I need to populate
            End If
        Next i
        wbkS.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Filename = Dir()
        c = c + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox "Yay! I just combined " & c & " reports for you!" 
End Sub
```

Does it have to do with how I'm defining my destination worksheet? It is pasting in the right places the right information, just from a completely different source file a few levels up in the directory I'm running this in. What's confusing is that it seems completely at random times and only starts taking place after I load it up with more than a few files to run through. It almost seems that at some point it's reading from a source file elsewhere and then overwriting a good chunk of data with blanks.

Under A LOT of pressure to get this working before Monday (and I thought it was until I just noticed that it wasn't) so any help would be appreciated. It's driving me insane! Remember that I'm a relative noob!

Comment: The first problem I can see (apart from `i` being declared as a `Variant` rather than as a `Long`, but that won't make it not work, just poor practice) is that `If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i).Value) Then` should be `If Not IsEmpty(wshs.Range("A" & i).Value) Then` or else it will look at the ActiveSheet (which may or may not be `Worksheets(1)` in the source workbook) to determine whether column A is empty.

Comment: Another bad thing (but I can't see how it will affect you in the way you are describing) is the `On Error Resume Next`.  I assume you put that there to stop it giving errors if a `Workbook` didn't contain a `Worksheet` (i.e. maybe just a `Chart` sheet) but you never cancel it with a `On Error GoTo 0` so it is applying to your whole code once it reaches that statement once.  That would be better written as `If wbks.Worksheets.Count > 0 Then` with an `End If` just before your `wbks.Close`.

Comment: The bug mentioned in my first comment could explain blanks being written to the destination.  Users adding or deleting rows to the workbooks that they completed could also cause you problems.  The `On Error` issue could cause data to be sourced from the first worksheet in the **destination** workbook.  But I see nothing in your code that would explain why workbooks other than `Path & "*.xlsx"` (or your master workbook) are being accessed.

Comment: Oh, and you should define all your variables - `Path` and `wshs` are undefined.  It is **highly** recommended to include `Option Explicit` in your code.  (And, hopefully finally, I just wanted to mention that this is one of the better pieces of code I have seen on here from a new user!!)

Comment: Thanks for all the help @YowE3K! I managed to find the culprit - the issue wasn't with the code but rather one of the files I got back had a filter on and then had the column hidden. Unfortunately a bunch of rows there indeed had data that wasn't cleared and as such it was overwriting the previously compiled data. Your suggestions have been very valuable though for getting stuff optimized. Now just have to optimize finding non-blank rows without running through, say 1000 rows.